# call javascript function with parameter from code behind

Tags: c#, asp.net, google-maps

hii, i have to call a function to display a google map. the code is in .aspx page and i have to call the function from the corresponding .aspx.cs page. 
my problem is that when i call the function without any parameter it works fine and the map is displayed. however as soon as i try to send a string as argument the map doesnt get displayed. !!

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Type.GetType("System.String"), "addScript", "initialize()", true);
```

when i use this statement the map gets displayed. but when i write

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Type.GetType("System.String"), "addScript", "initialize('" + finaladd + "','" + name_and_add + "')", true);
```

its not worknig.. finaladd and name_and_add are two strings. they are however quite long ones.

Comment: Could you show finaladd and name_and_add sample values?

Comment: its a string of name and address of employees and they are seperated by '~' . in the javascript function the string is split using .split method.

Comment: You'll have to debug it. Ignore how you generate the Javascript for now, and see if the Javascript itself is OK. Do the values look correct, and very important in Javascript, a single line? Use "\n" (backslash n, not a newline) if you need a newline.

Comment: And, most importantly: does it work with manually entered Javascript?

Comment: hey bart,y is it that i need to escape backslashes.???

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that both `finaladd` and `name_and_add` are properly escaped. In this case you need to make sure that the strings don't contain any single quote `'` character.

The easiest way to accomplish this is a simple `.Replace("'", @"\'")` on both variables.

Comment: Backslashes need to be escaped, too.